# Hover over li item and do something to child img

Tags: html, css

Is there an easy way to do this with css?

I have a list like so..

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="..."><li>
<ul>
```

Now the default css for this is..

```
ul li img{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

how can I set the `opacity: 1;` if you hover over the list item??

Answer (score 4):

It should be as simple as this:

```
ul li img {
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I new there must of been a simple solution, I didnt know you could put a selector after the `:hover`